# How to automatically include http:// in web view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a web view in Xcode and a text field where you can enter URL addresses. The only problem is when entering an address you have to manually put in http:// or it won't recognize it. How would I be able to do this and what would the code look like? On the other hand, how would I be able to change the text field address when I click on a link? Because when I click on a link the URL stays at the previous page. For example, I type in google.com and the when I click on a link the text field stays at google. Any ideas on how to this?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you process the URL, you'll probably get some sort of NSString from the input text field.  Suppose you have something like so:

```
NSString *awesomeURLString = [myCoolTextField text];
NSURL *awesomeURL = [NSURL urlWithString:awesomeURLString];
```

Where you create "awesomeURLString", you can prefix http:// onto it using the "stringWithFormat" method.

```
NSString *awesomeURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[myCoolTextField text]];
```

This would make the end result like so:

```
NSString *awesomeURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[myCoolTextField text]];
NSURL *awesomeURL = [NSURL urlWithString:awesomeURLString];
```

In the future, one should also consider adding logic to see if they already have a protocol in place before automatically adding one.